# Detect Car Wheel Position?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have an image:

[image: Car]

I want to detect wheel empty position dynamically, is it possible?

If not possible please let me know, my work involves PHP/XML/Actionscript where actionscript get image url from xml generated by PHP,

User uploads car image through php admin panel, then passes url to actionscript through XML and actionscript should load image and let him choose the wheel and test on the car.

If you have another solution let me know?

Comment: Interesting - a computer vision problem!  I don't know that much about the subject, but here's what I'd try: extract the outline (use brightness/color to separate foreground from background, then edge detection to assemble the outline as a sequence of line segments), then look for places in the outline that have a radius of curvature within the expected range for the tires and also cover a large enough arc (~180 degrees).

Comment: Doing a hough transform with circles should give you all circles in the image, then you only have to find the right circles. Of course, you'd still need to extract the outline first.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem from computer vision and the keywords your want to search are "pattern recognition". If you would like to make it fully automated, try [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) library. You basically want to define the arc and then look for it. I am quite sure the library can provide this functionality, but it doesn't have a port to Actionscript. You can look into the source codes, but the algorithms are not easy.

---

But personaly I'd let the users pick the wheel areas for me. Simply load the image, display it and let the user click on the picture twice to set the positions (and size) of wheels. A lot of image reconginiton/manipulation software does it this way to detect eyes in faces etc.